# The parameterized query '(@Date date,@DocNo nvarchar(2),@CostCenter nvarchar(11),@Transac' expects the parameter '@AccountID', which was not supplied

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010, prepared-statement

I am stuck in strange situation. i have one form containing 1 DateTimePicker 2 Textboxes, 1 Combobox and one datagridview.
I have set the coding using VB.Net which save the data in one row of SQL Database from Textboxes DTPickers, Combobox and all rows of Datagridview simultaneously. the data saved successfully But i am getting this error messege despite AccountID is not null. Before suggesting DBNull.Value, i want to clarify here that if i use this option it saves one extra row in the database taking existing values from DTpicker, Textboxes and Comboboxes. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
con.Open()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into Transs (Date,DocNo,CostCenter,TransactionID,AccountID,AccountName,AccountType,Debit,Credit,Text) values (@Date,@DocNo,@CostCenter,@TransactionID,@AccountID,@AccountName,@AccountType,@Debit,@Credit,@Text)", con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocNo", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostCenter", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionID", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", row.Cells("Column1").Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", row.Cells("Column2").Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", row.Cells("Column3").Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Debit", row.Cells("Column4").Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credit", row.Cells("Column5").Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", row.Cells("Column6").Value)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
Next
con.Close()
MsgBox("Record saved successfully!")
```

Comment: Does the `DataGridView` have an extra “empty” row at the bottom of the grid? If so, those values will be null and your loop is going to use that row unless you check for it.

Comment: No extra row there. But in first instance why am facing this error "AccountiD not supplied" while AccountID cell is filled.

Comment: I am still not sure if I follow. So, when you try to “insert” a row into the DB from each row in the grid, you are getting an error stating that “AccountID” is null? If this is the case, then you should trace the code in the loop through the grid rows to see “which” “AccountID” is `null` in the grid. Or is there something else going on?

Comment: JohnG you are right there was extra row in DGV which i eliminated from the loop. Now its done. Thanks